# Automatically Rename Files to date (YY-MM-DD)

Tags: linux, raspbian

Is it possible to automatically rename (mp3) files, to there date in YY/MM/DD format, using files on raspbian?

I have a audio recorder set up to automatically record mp3 files to a specific folder and upload them to the cloud. I want to name them their date beforehand so the (google drive) folder has files like 19-09-05.mp3, not XXXX125Y2G.MP3.

I am not sure how to automate file renaming, since I am a linux noob, but I was told it is possible.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this one liner here should do the trick.  Test it with cp rather than mv.  Also the slashes reak havoc with bash, I put dashes in instead.

```
for i in $(ls *.MP3); do d=$(date "+%y-%m-%d"-$i); mv $i $d; done
```

Comment: how do I automatically do it though, because I want all files added to the folder (that are mp3s) to have that happen, not just when I run the command